# PATCH /subscriptions/{sid} returning "InternalServerError"

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In the **Azure API Management REST API Subscription entity**,
when I call

`PATCH /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2014-02-14-preview`

with a request body containing `primaryKey=yyyyyyyyyyy`, it returns an unexpected `500 Internal Server Error` with body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Request processing failed due to internal error.",
        "details": null
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776325.aspx#UpdateSubscription

Comment: Have you tried `PUT` instead?

Comment: `PUT` "subscribes the specified user to the specified product" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776325.aspx#SubscribeProduct while `PATCH` is used to partially modify a resource (according to RFC 5789 and Azure's docs). I am trying to update the `primaryKey` of an existing user subscription.

Comment: Today I've learned that there's `PATCH` verb in the first place. The typical approach is to use `PUT` both for creation and for updating. So this is why I ask if you tried `PUT`.

Comment: Can you post your entire request including the body?